# NDK: Passing Jfloat array from Java to C++ via GetByteArrayElements?

Tags: java, android, c++, arrays, android-ndk

I remembered that there were 4 Bytes per float.
And I can use GetByteArrayElements to pass a byte array from Java to C++.
But Since 4 Bytes is equal to a float, can I use GetByteArrayElements to pass in a Java byte and manipulate it?

Since only GetByteArrayElements and GetPrimitiveArrayCritical would return a actual pointer of data and push speed.

Comment: Why can't you use `GetFloatArrayElements` and cast the pointer to a `jbyte*`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this demonstrates what you want to do. If I have misunderstood your question, please comment.

In Java:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(WHATEVER_BUFFER_SIZE);
FloatBuffer floats = buffer.asFloatBuffer();
your_Java_native_method(floats);
// use floats to deal with data in Java
```

In native code (C++):

```
void your_JNI_method_name(JNIEnv env, jobject thiz, jobject javaBuffer) {
    float *nativeBuffer = (float*)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(javaBuffer);
    jlong bufferSize = env->GetDirectBufferCapacity(javaBuffer);
    // do whatever you want with the data in native code
}
```

Comment: access from Java to **`DirectFloatBuffer`** may be significantly slower than to **`float[]`**.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `GetByteArrayElements()` to access `float[]`. You can use `GetPrimitiveArrayCritical()` within its limitations, and this will be as fast as it could be.

But your assumption is wrong: `GetFloatArrayElements()` will not necessarily copy the elements. If it does not copy, it will give you the actual pointer to the Java array, and if you need byte-by-byte access to this array in your C++ code, you can reinterpret it as `unsigned char *`.